# Autosys R11.3 : Error on log file size limit

Tags: unix, autosys

Just had a migration from Autosys 4.5 to R11.3.

After the migration to R11.3, Autosys jobs have been failing when the log file reaches a size of 800 MB.

This did not happen before the migration, when Autosys 4.5 was used.

Is there a way to configure the file size limit/cap in Autosys R11.3?

Has anyone experienced this issue in using Autosys R11.3 and resolved it?  If so, can you please advise on what can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Open a ticket with CA support. There is a patch for that issue.